# Convexity of implicit functions

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, implicit-function-theorem, implicit-function

Are there any sufficient conditions which guarantee us that a curve defined implicitly by the equation $F(x,y) = 0$ will be convex or concave? Assuming the conditions of the implicit function theorem are satisfied. I am asking about something else rather than looking at the second derivative, as it is not always as easy.

Comment: It is not a duplicate @KurtG. because I can't just go straight away to find the second derivative. The example I am looking at is: $F\left(a,t\right)=\frac{\partial }{\partial a}\int _0^{p\left(a,t\right)}\sqrt{1+\left(arx^{r-1}\right)^2}dx\:=0$, where $p\left(a,t\right)=\left(\frac{t+ak^r}{a}\right)^{\frac{1}{r}}$ and $a, t, k, r > 0$. The second partial derivatives are obviously a nightmare.

Comment: Looks so. Yes. And $t$ is the function of $a$ given implicitly by $F(a,t)=0$? Where is that from?

Comment: @KurtG. $a$ is defined as a function of $t$. It came from an optimization problem, the expression (before the derivation) is the length of the curve $y = -ax^r + c$, from 0 to its right intersection point, under the constraint that it must pass through the point $(k,t)$.

Comment: Please give the full background of this. It sounds like you are looking for a parameter that maximizes/minimizes the length of a curve. Perhaps it is not even necessary to find out why an implicit function is convex.